# Using jQuery without document.ready function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that will get respond from server the respond will contain some buttons, I want to control them with jQuery, but the problem is that they won't exist once the page is opened so I can't control them with 
`$(document).ready(function()`

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: When you add the buttons to the DOM (append to document/element) they will be available for manipulation. If you want to change the buttons prior to that, you can also use actual DOM functions to build the elements, grab a reference to them and change them.

Comment: Post your relevant regarding ajax request

Comment: Also, document.ready is optional. It is in no way required. All it does is make sure that the DOM is loaded before trying to query for and use the elements inside the DOM (usually after dom is ready and before body.onload fires). You can use jquery perfectly fine without it.

Comment: sorry I did not understand what you mean but the server code will be like this echo"<input type="button" id="a">" when I am trying to cotrol it document.ready(function(){$("#a").click(function(){....... it is no working

Comment: But use relevant ajax callback ONCE element added to the DOM. Btw, you didnt tell what you want to do. If binding events, then delegate them instead

Comment: control the buttons with in ajax response block after adding them to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried event delegation?

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

You just need an empty wrapper element where you will render the buttons in the future, after page loads. So, when you add the buttons, you will be able to interact with them.

At the beginning, the wrapper element must exists in your HTML:

```
<div id="buttonsWrapper"></div>
```

After that, after the ajax call is completed, then you append the buttons from the server to that element:

```
<div id="buttonsWrapper">
    <button>From server</buttom>
    <button>From server</buttom>
</div>
```

With this JS, you delegate the click event on the wrapper "#buttonsWrapper" element:

```
$(function(){
    $("#buttonsWrapper").on( "click", "button", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log( $( this ).text() );
    });
}());
```

With event delegation, it doesn't matter if you add the buttons after page loads. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Make prepare function in document and when the buttons load run it!

```
<script>
   function loadOK()
   {
      // put your document ready codes here
   }

   $.post("your.url.address.for.get.buttons",data)
        .done(function(data){ loadOK(); })
        .error(function(){ alert("ajax cant complate";)});
 </script>
```

after your buttons added call this function.

Comment: What is the purpose of wrapping ready pseudo event here? Or maybe you mean just put its content?!

Comment: $(document).ready(function) will run just document load complate. But when you get some thing extra after load with ajax, you call ajax success function after ajax load complete.

Comment: Thx for the edit, makes sense now ;)